# square bracket array access and handlebars template

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm working on a node project with handlebars tempting engine. I have a very large object I need to represent in a table. The user gets to pick which columns they want to see.

I have a varable called columns that holds the user's selected columns, we'll pretend it looks like

```
columns = ['name','email']
```

and I have an array of large objects

```
items = [{
    name:'foo',
    email:'foo@foo.com',
    otherPropN:'other...'
}, ...]
```

Here was my first attempt at rendering a table with only the columns name and email.

```
      <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    {{#each columns}}
                        <th>{{this}}</th>
                    {{/each}}
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{#each items}}
                        {{#each ../columns}}
                            <td>{{*WHAT TO PUT HERE!*}}</td>
                        {{/each}}
                    {{/each}}
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

I need to get back into the scope of item so I can say `item[column]` But, I'm not sure how to do that.

In EJS this is what I would do.

```
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <% columns.forEach(function(column){ %>
                        <th><%=column%></th>
                    <% }); %>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                                  <% item.forEach(function(item){ 
                         columns.forEach(function(column){ %>
                        <td><%=item[column]%></td>

                        <% });
                                   }); %>
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your data structure isn't quite clear to me. Please elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities immediately come to mind:

1. Modify Handlebars with a custom helper.
2. Modify your data to better aline with how Handlebars thinks.

The first option is a simple helper like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('property', function(o, k) {
    return o[k];
});
```

Then you can say:

```
<td>{{property ../this this}}</td>
```

inside your template. **Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Dedt6/

The second option is to do the data wrangling in JavaScript before the template sees anything:

```
// Or the nested for-loop equivalent
var items_mangled = items.map(function(item) {
    return columns.map(function(column) {
        return item[column];
    });
});
```

then handle `items_mangled` to the template function as `items: items_mangled` and your template would have:

```
{{#each items}}
    <tr>
        {{#each this}}
            <td>{{this}}</td>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Basically, convert your array and array-of-objects into a single array-of-arrays in JavaScript so that Handlebars can work with things it likes the most (arrays). Handlebars prefers that most of your logic is done outside the template after all. **Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vsBFS/

Comment: How would I regester a helper for node?

Comment: You'd just need to call `Handlebars.registerHelper(...)` before using your template. I'd probably put them all in a single `handlebars_helpers.js` file and then run it right after you pull in Handlebars itself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I get it now.
I would make two separate template objects - the overall table, and a 'row' template. Then you would have to do a little bit of javascript logic rendering each passing each row template the appropriate model.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure I understand. What would the two objects look like?

Comment: I've elaborated on the question some